# Restricting a Set Range in Excel VBA based on an if condition

Tags: excel, vba, range

I would like to set a range in Excel VBA in order to later address it, transform it to HTML and paste it into an email. In general, this all works fine with the following lines (only where I define the range):

```
Set MySheet = ExeWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = MySheet.Range("A6:L17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Later on, I use a function "RangetoHTML(rng As Range)" to paste it into an Email body. Works like a charm (taken from here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm).

However, I would like to limit the range to include only those rows that match either the string "AAA" or "BBB" in column F. All other rows should not be included - but not deleted!

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, some more practical than others, some more efficient than others.  Arguably, the easiest and fastest will be to filter column F by your criteria and set the range to visible cells (just like you've done).  Alternatively, you could loop by row and test each cell in the column, either using Union to build a range on the fly, or creating and concatenating a string that you convert to a range, or create an array of rows, or about a dozen other variations of the same concept.  Neither strategy deletes anything.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is indeed, as suggested by ProfoundlyOblivious to set an auto filter before:

```
MySheet.Range("A6:L17").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=AAA"
```

The restriction to only include visible fields into the range will do the rest.

To select more filters you can simply add them:

```
MySheet.Range("A6:L17").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=AAA", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=BBB"
```